# How get thumbnails from a specific directory with content provider

Tags: java, android

I have this code that want to extract all thumbnails but the array result is empty and logically list bitmaps too.Where path is "/emulated/storage/legacy", context is the Activity and the query is with condition. Any Idea? Thanks.

```
    public void getThubmnails() {

    String[] cols = {
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
    };

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

    Cursor cursor = this.context.getContentResolver().query(
            uri,
            cols,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?",
            new String[] {
                    path,
            },
            null
    );

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID);
    int name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int tipo = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE);
    int path = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);


    String[] result = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        result[cursor.getPosition()] = "ID: " + String.valueOf(cursor.getLong(index))
                + " " + "NAME: " + cursor.getString(name)
                + " " + "MIME_TYPE: " + cursor.getString(tipo)
                + " " + "DATA: " + cursor.getString(path);

        this.bitmap.add(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                this.context.getContentResolver(),
                cursor.getLong(index),
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null));
    }

}
```